# How to get a value from response body in Gatling?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I've tried different approaches that I've found on Gatling.io, but my problem still persists. 
There's an API which returns a short response in JSON format when I send a GET request.

GET request:

http://localhost:some_port/api/endpoint1?parameter1=1234&parameter2=5678

Response:

**{"transaction":"6d638b9b-f131-41b1-bd07-0d1c6a1d4bcc","reference":"some_text"}**

I need to get transaction value from the response and use it in another request.

Next request:

http://localhost:some_port/api/endpoint2?transaction=$transactionValue&parameter=8

So far I've tried using regex, jsonPath with Int or String values but the result is 0 or None.

This is my scenario code so far:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class class1 extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("http://localhost:port")
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .acceptHeader("text/html,application/json")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.9,hr;q=0.8,sr;q=0.7,bs;q=0.6")
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64)")

    val headers = Map(
        "Content-Type" -> "application/json")

    val uri1 = "http://localhost:port/api/endpoint1"
    val uri2 = "http://localhost:port/api/endpoint2"

    val scn = scenario("getEndpoint1")
        .exec(http("endpoint1")
            .get("/api/endpoint1?parameter1=1234&parameter2=5678")
            .headers(headers)
      .check(jsonPath("$.transaction").findAll.saveAs("transaction")))
    .pause(3)
    .exec(session => {
      val transaction = session("transaction").asOption[String]
      session
    }).exec(http("endpoint2").get(uri2 +s"/transaction=${"transaction"}&parameter=8").headers(headers))

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

If you have any suggestions or see something I'm doing wrong, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `.check(jsonPath("$..transaction")).saveAs("transaciton")`? Checking out this [example](https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/#step-03-use-dynamic-data-with-feeders-and-checks) might help anyway...

Comment: I've tried that option, and you're right that was the problem with the code, but there is another problem. When I try to use the transaction variable out of the session it results in "failed to execute: No attribute named 'transaction' is defined", I've tried also to assign that value to a variable but the result was the same (couldn't use that variable outside of session). I'm currently trying to figure out a way to pass that value outside of the session or finding another approach to this problem. Have any ideas?

Comment: Hmm might be a typo... You misspelled transaction in the saveAs-method: .saveAs("transa**cit**on").

Comment: That was a typo when I edited the code in the post it doesn't exist in my actual code.

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution. 
As [Phonolog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5730444/phonolog) said,  jsonPath was not looking at the right parameter, correct was `jsonPath("$..transaction)`. Next problem was that EL variable couldn't be used outside of session. My fix was to forget calling the session at all and to find a different approach. `jsonPath("$..transaction").findAll.saveAs("transaction")` was saving a Vector which created complications, the solution was to use `find` instead of `findAll`. The rest was pretty much straightforward.

Comment: @SinisaBrzak please do post the code that worked as an answer (it's perfectly fine to answer your own question on SO).

Comment: @PauloMerson you can see the solution in the comment above yours

Comment: Providing a full answer to this post would have been helpful, as @PauloMerson suggested